# How to plot hazard function in R using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival, hazard

There's a book called "Event History Analysis with R" by G. Broström. But it provides minimal R code for whatever concepts are presented. I'd like to plot a hazard function, how do I do that? I want the exact same plots as given [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTmMQ.png). The plots shown are in [this chapter](http://ehar.se/r/ehar2/proportional-hazards-and-cox-regression.html#sec:ph3). If possible, I'd like to do the same plots using ggplot2.

I've done survival and cumulative hazard plots using ggplot2 that look [better](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoVde.png), using the code:

```
library(survminer)

fit <- survfit(Surv(enter, exit, event) ~ male, data = df_final)

ggsurvplot(fit, title = "Survival Function") +
  xlab("Age in years") +
  ylab("Survival")
```

My data looks like this:

| id | male | enter | exit | event |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1 | 0.00 | 13.34 | 1 |
| 001 | 1 | 13.34 | 45.00 | 0 |
| 002 | 1 | 0.00 | 27.00 | 0 |
| 003 | 0 | 0.00 | 23.60 | 1 |
| 003 | 0 | 23.60 | 27.00 | 1 |
| 003 | 0 | 27.00 | 67.00 | 0 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the R codes to reproduce the figures in the book from the book's [GitHub repo](https://github.com/goranbrostrom/EHAR2).

For example, for the figures you are trying to replicate you could copy and paste the basic data wrangling code from the [repo](https://github.com/goranbrostrom/EHAR2/blob/683ea2a1c0ce253a78fa6278ac574ce3b25c48c3/03-cox.Rmd#LL89C1-L111C12) and convert the base R plotting code to `ggplot2` like so where I also made use of a bit of `dplyr`, `tidyr` and `patchwork` to combine the subplots:

```
library(eha)
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

females <- swepop[
  swepop$sex == "women" & swepop$year %in% 2001:2020,
  c("age", "pop", "year")
]
females$deaths <- swedeaths[swedeaths$sex == "women" &
  swedeaths$year %in% 2001:2020, "deaths"]
females <- aggregate(females[c("pop", "deaths")], by = females["age"], FUN = sum)
females$mort <- females$deaths / females$pop

males <- swepop[
  swepop$sex == "men" & swepop$year %in% 2001:2020,
  c("age", "pop")
]
males$deaths <- swedeaths[swedeaths$sex == "men" &
  swedeaths$year %in% 2001:2020, "deaths"]
males <- aggregate(males[c("pop", "deaths")], by = males["age"], FUN = sum)
males$mort <- males$deaths / males$pop

dat <- list(
  males = males,
  females = females
) |>
  dplyr::bind_rows(.id = "sex")

p1 <- ggplot(dat, aes(age, mort, linetype = sex)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_linetype_discrete(
    labels = c(males = "Men", females = "Women"),
    breaks = c("males", "females")
  ) +
  labs(x = "Age", y = "Hazards", linetype = NULL) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    legend.position = c(0, 1),
    legend.justification = c(0, 1),
    legend.box.background = element_rect(color = "black")
  )

p2 <- dat |> 
  select(sex, age, mort) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = sex, values_from = mort) |> 
  mutate(hazard = males / females) |> 
  ggplot(aes(age, hazard)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 1) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(x = "Age", y = "Hazard ratio", linetype = NULL) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    legend.position = c(0, 1),
    legend.justification = c(0, 1),
    legend.box.background = element_rect(color = "black")
  )

p1 + p2 +
  plot_annotation(
    title = "Female and male mortality by age, Sweden 2001-2020.",
    subtitle = "The right hand panel shows the ratio between the male and female mortality by age."
  )
```

[image]

Comment: How do I do the same using a Surv(enter, exit, event) object? I've made some edits to my question including some more information. Thanks for your help.